# Is there a way I can stop the default icon from appearing and stop it from being oneclick?

Tags: json, npm, electron, electron-builder

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "password-generator",
  "productName": "Password Generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Password generator desktop app",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "build-installer": "electron-builder",
    "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\""
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "password-generator"
  },
  "win": {
    "target": [
      "nsis"
    ],
    "icon": "src/icon.png"
  },
  "nsis": {
    "installerIcon": "src/icon.png",
    "uninstallerIcon": "src/icon.png",
    "uninstallDisplayName": "Password Generator",
    "oneClick": false,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "JipBit",
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "password_generator"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "electron": "9.1.0"
  }
}
```

**Information:** When running the build command, I go to my dist folder and find that the icon for the installer is the default windows one. And after the installation is complete, the icon for the desktop app is the default electron one. The desktop app name worked out fine. The icon.png works when I start up the program and also works after I installed it when opening the app. But the icon for the installer and app on my desktop itself is the windows and electron icon. The icon.png is located in my src folder and I've already tried a few things that haven't seemed to work. Not only that but disabling one click didn't work as the setup.exe is still one click. These things are also printing out when building the app saying it will be set to default icon and oneclick=true. I don't even think the NSIS setup worked either, I can't confirm that thought. I'm currently using the electron framework by GitHub. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you must define the icon in the target array of your win object like this:

```
"build": {
    "appId": "password-generator"
},
"win": {
    "target": [
        "nsis",
        "icon": "src/icon.png"
    ]
}
```

for the oneclick i have a working example:

```
"nsis": {
  "createDesktopShortcut": true,
  "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
  "allowElevation": true,
  "oneClick": false,
  "perMachine": true,
  "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
}
```

please read also the information for oneclick [here](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis)

Comment: It still isn't working. I'm getting the same output in my terminal and when then build is finished.

Comment: Update: Putting the icon.png under the build key fixed the icon. The only issue now is everything under the NSIS key doesn't seem to work.